# How to add checkboxes for each value in dropdown using simple_form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In my view i am trying to bind the values to input field using simple_form as below

```
<%= simple_form_for @ruby, url:{action: 'create'}, html: {class: 'form'}  do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name, collection: ruby.distinctnames, :label => "Select Names" %>
<% end %>
```

Now, the values I get as dropdown.

But, I would like to have checkboxes in front of every value using simple_form gem.

or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [collection_check_boxes](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_check_boxes) method.

```
<%= simple_form_for @ruby, url:{action: 'create'}, html: {class: 'form'}  do |f| %>
  <div class="ruby-names-wrapper collapsed"
    <%= link_to 'Ruby Names', '#', onclick: 'this.parrent.toggleClass("collapsed")' %>
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper"
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :ruby_names, @ruby.distinctnames, :to_s, :to_s, { multiple: true }  %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in your css:

```
.ruby-names-wrapper.collapsed .checkbox-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.ruby-names-wrapper .checkbox-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I get the following error
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for "Prakash":String):

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash Edited response. I thought you have some model. As you have the array of strings, you could just call `to_s` on each

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks it worked. But, as per my code earlier, all the values comes in drop down. Now as per your suggested code all the values are coming with check boxes but not in drop down.

Comment: Then you should wrap it in the container and add `js` for hide/show.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Sysuiev. It worked.
Also, can you please look at this another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805333/how-to-pass-selected-value-from-dropdown-and-access-it-as-a-parameter-for-cascad